Interrupt not working after firmware update in APM8S007
I am working with the APM8S007 microcontroller, an 8051-based 8-bit microcontroller, and I need to implement firmware update functionality for it. I have developed a bootloader that receives the firmware binary file via Tera Term and writes it to the flash memory at a location different from where the bootloader resides.
I can successfully jump from the bootloader to the application, and the application executes as expected. However, the interrupts are not functioning—ISRs are not being invoked at all. I have tried changing the start address of the interrupt vector table as per the reference manual, which allows for such modifications, but this has not resolved the issue.
Desired Behavior:
The application includes UART functionality with interrupt configuration. When data is sent from Tera Term, the application should echo the received data back to the terminal. Additionally, the application features GPIO interrupt functionality, where pressing a push button should trigger the GPIO interrupt.
Problem:
The issue is that neither the UART nor the GPIO interrupts are invoked, meaning the respective ISR handlers are not being called. Both interrupts are correctly configured, and the global interrupt is enabled. Since the application’s start address is 0x1000, the interrupt vector table address has also been adjusted accordingly as per the reference manual.
Note: The application runs perfectly fine except for the interrupt functionality.
If anyone can provide assistance, please let me know.

No code, no debugging data. All we can do is guess. What debugging have you done?
